# make database value into variable

Tags: php

i have added a test code.please check it.

```
 $products_text_box['text_box'] = "test";
    $test = "demo"
```

when i print this echo $products_text_box['text_box']; then , it will displaplay the output test.

but i want to display output demo which is store in $test variable to get it i have to convert test into $test.

how can i do this?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking. Please edit your question and try to express in different words what your problem is and what you want to do.

Comment: see this: http://codepad.org/tVInj11C

Comment: i have seen it GBD but the value of $products_text_box['text_box'] is come from database. not static.

Comment: Can you paste your original code ?

Comment: What you're looking for is variable variables, and they are as evil as eval. `echo ${$products_text_box['text_box']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is with [eval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but be warned:

The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Another example from construction of variable name:
[example](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/483_Double-Dollars-in-PHP.html)

```
$test = "demo"
$products_text_box['text_box'] = "test";
echo $$products_text_box['text_box'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't encourage using eval().

Why would you want to do this. Be more specific on what you want to do.. I would be able to help you with alternatives